Cubo rotable en Android Studio
busco hacer una app móvil que permita crear 4 cubos, y al reconocer tu movimiento en la cámara, lo puedas trasladar y girar. Sim embargo he intentado hacerlo con OpenGL y con Screenview, pero no lo he logrado. Necesito alguna guía de como empezar o de plano, un tutorial de cómo lograrlo. Los problemas principales que he visto se basan en que los tutoriales son tan antiguos o ambiguos que son obsoletos, además a veces mi computadora empieza a hacer sonar un buzzer al correr el programa, teniendo que reiniciarla siempre que sucede.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
